# Add more value into data object laravel api

Tags: php, laravel

```
$st = 'Something';
return Response::json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "User found",
            "st" => $st,
            "data"    => Auth::user()->load(['ch' => function ($query) {
                            $query->noGu()
                                        ->with('sp');
                    },
                    'sp' => function($query){
                        return Auth::user()->sp;
                    }])
        ], 200);
```

How can i $st into "data" object i tried 'st' => $st, does not work for me please suggest thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
        $st = 'Something';
    return Response::json([
                "success" => true,
                "message" => "User found",
                "st" => $st,
                 //Take the use statement
                "data"    => Auth::user()->load(['ch' => function ($query) use ($st) {
                                //Now you can use $st inside this function
                                $query->noGu()->with('sp');
                        },
                        'sp' => function($query){
                            return Auth::user()->sp;
                        }])
            ], 200);
```

Comment: How can i use $st now

Comment: "st":[{"st":"something"}] need response something like that

Comment: return Response::json([
                    "success" => true,
                    "message" => "User found",
                    "st" => $st,
                    "data"    => Auth::user()->load(['ch' => function ($query) use ($st) {

                                    $query->noGu()->with('sp');
                            },
                            'sp' => function($query){
                                return Auth::user()->sp;
                            }, 'st' => $st])
                ], 200);

Comment: How about writing cleaner code?

You can use $st inside this function where you have included it with use($st), like in any other place... echo $st;